Facebook Professional Mode post sharing issue
I’m having trouble with Facebook's Professional Mode. When I create a post with text, a photo, and a video, everything looks fine. But when the post is shared, only the video appears. The text and photo are missing.
Key Points:
Issue: Posts in Professional Mode share only the video, not the text or photo.
Classic Mode: No issues; all content shares correctly.
Devices: Problem occurs on both mobile and desktop.
Other Posts: Sharing posts from others in Professional Mode works fine.

What I’ve Tried:
Adjusted privacy settings.
Tested different content combinations.
Compared settings with another account.
Cleared cache and cookies.
Disabled third-party extensions.

Action Taken:
Reported to Facebook Support.
Seeking community help for similar experiences or solutions.

Has anyone else faced this? Any known fixes or tips?
Thanks!in advance
